# How to find a vector from a list of vectors that is nearest to all other vectors using Python?

Tags: python, math, vector, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a list of vectors as a numpy array.

```
[[ 1., 0., 0.],
 [ 0., 1., 2.] ...]
```

They all have the same dimension. How do I find out that in the vector space which vector is the closest to all the other vectors in the array? Is there scipy or sklearn function that calculates this?

`Update`:

By "closest", I meant the cosine and the Euclidean distance.

`Update 2`:

Let's say I have 4 vectors (a,b,c,d), and the Cosine distance between the vectors are:

a,b = 0.2

a,c = 0.9

a,d = 0.7

b,c = 0.5

b,d = 0.75

c,d = 0.8

So for each, vector a,b,c,d I get :

```
{
    'a': [1,0.2,0.9,0.7],

    'b': [0.2,1,0.5,0.75],

    'c' : [0.9,0.5,1,0.75],

    'd' : [0.7,0.75,0.8,1]
}
```

Is there a way of saying let's say vector d is the one that is the most similar to a,b,c ?

Comment: you most likely brute force it. and how do you define distance? is it the euclidean one?

Comment: And how do you define "closest to all others"?

Comment: By "closest",  I meant the cosine and the Euclidean distance. ( added it to the question. )

Comment: Is the closest the one with the least upper bound of distance to the other vectors? Or the least *total* distance to other vectors? Or what? Can you show us what kind of calculation you are aiming for?

Comment: What is your problem, can you show us what you tried so far so we can have a better understanding of what you are asking ?

Comment: You state two different ways of measuring distance (cosine and Euclidean). You need to pick one. Or do you mean some strange combination of the two? And you still have not explained what you mean by "closest to all the other vectors in the array."

Comment: I added what I mean in *Update 2*

Comment: FYI, this is equivalent to doing K-medoids with k=1

Answer (score 2):

You could brute force it something like this. Note that this is O(n^2), and will get slow for large n.

```
import numpy as np

def cost_function(v1, v2):
    """Returns the square of the distance between vectors v1 and v2."""
    diff = np.subtract(v1, v2)
    # You may want to take the square root here
    return np.dot(diff, diff)

n_vectors = 5
vectors = np.random.rand(n_vectors,3)

min_i = -1
min_cost = 0
for i in range (0, n_vectors):
    sum_cost = 0.0
    for j in range(0, n_vectors):
        sum_cost = sum_cost + cost_function(vectors[i,:],vectors[j,:])
    if min_i < 0 or min_cost > sum_cost:
        min_i = i
        min_cost = sum_cost
    print('{} at {}: {:.3f}'.format(i, vectors[i,:], sum_cost))
print('Lowest cost point is {} at {}: {:.3f}'.format(min_i, vectors[min_i,:], min_cost))
```